# Return type of async functions which return un-awaited promises

Tags: typescript

I've come across a library where I need to return an un-awaited promise from within an async function. However, whenever I try to do the typings - Typescript assumes that the return value has already been resolved.

Here is what it boils down to:

```js
async function getNumber(): Promise<number> {
  return 5;
}

async function getUnawaitedPromise(): Promise<number> {
  await fetch('...');

  return getNumber();
}
```

This doesn't throw any typescript errors. However for the async function `getUnawaitedPromise()`  I'd expect the return type to be `Promise<Promise<number>>`.

I thought it would be analagous to this case:

```js
function getNumber(): number {
  return 5;
}

async function mustReturnPromise(): Promise<number> {
  await fetch('...');

  return getNumber();
}
```

I expected the return result to be `Promise<ReturnTypeOfGetNumber>`.

Answer (score 1):

`return await getNumberAsync();` and `return getNumberAsync()` will return an exactly the same thing in JavaScript, a `Promise<number>`. There is no need to use any nesting such as `Promise<Promise<Promise<type>>>` no matter how many layers there are.

The only time when it really matters is using a `return await` in a try-catch block.

Otherwise a `return await` is not recommended, see eslint rule `no-return-await`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think it does return the same thing though. The reason is if I call `await mustReturnPromise()` for the first case, I'd like it to resolve the async function, but then still return an unresolved promise. Similarly for the second case if I call `await mustReturnPromise()` it returns "whatever the result of the `getNumber()` function was.

Comment: "I'd like it to resolve the async function, but then still return an unresolved promise" - I don't think you can. A `Promise<Promise<T>>` is just a `Promise<T>`.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27711#issuecomment-476602716

Comment: Thanks, makes complete sense now that I think about it.